# Is the effect of "daemon-reload" inhibited during boot?

Tags: systemd, boot

I have a `systemd` service configured to start when the graphical session starts.

```winini
[Unit]
Description=My service
Requires=display-manager.service
After=graphical.target display-manager.service

< ... >

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

So far, this service started correctly on boot when enabled, so I assume no "trivial" errors (like syntax etc.).

However, a change was recently introduced in which the question whether to `enable` the service in the first place is decided based on a configuration file evaluated by a different `systemd` service queued earlier in the boot sequence. If it finds that the `My service` needs enabling, it will run `systemctl enable my.service` which is done correctly. The system journal shows the corresponding `systemd[1]: Reloading.` entry. If I place an additional `systemctl daemon-reload`, I get the `Reloading` message twice.

*However*, the `my.service` is not running when the graphical session is up.

- `systemctl status` reveals it to be enabled (but - as stated - not running):

  ```
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
  ```
- When inspecting the `graphical.target.wants` directory, it contains the symlink to `my.service`.

*If I now simply reboot the system, the `my.service` is started correctly on boot.*

This leads me to think that the `systemd` boot queue is not updated when it is being changed during the boot phase. Is that so, and if so, is there a remedy?

Comment: Not answering the question, but maybe you could work around this with a condition? eg [`ConditionPathExists=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionPathExists=)

Comment: If you enable a service, it's set to be started automatically for the _next_ boot. The current boot can't be the next boot, of course. If you're running `systemctl enable something`, perhaps you should just use `systemctl enable --now something`, instead? It will try to start the service immediately, but since it has dependencies, which are already in the boot sequence, it should be added to the sequence.

Comment: @muru I was hoping that the "reload" would also affect the running boot sequence. Using `--now` indeed tries to start the `my.service` immediately, but since that depends on a running graphical session (which is not started at that point), this means the boot process will hang. I might have to use a workaraund.